# How to order two arrays as a for manner

Tags: javascript, node.js

I mean:
I have two arrays, number, and name

```js
const number = ['91xxxx','1xxxx','92xxxx']
const name = ['Abhi','Arun','Aaron']
```

Here I want to order these two arrays in the following manner:

1st number in the array that is `number[0]`, its name must be `name[0]` and `number[1]`, for `name[1]`, like that.

But That arrays are user preference, what I mean is users can add their number and name there unlimitedly but I want to keep in the above manner, How should I do????

I have made a code:

```js
async function getAllOwners() {
   var nam = ''
   var num = ''
   number.map(async (nu) => {
      num = nu
   })
   name.map(async (na) => {
      nam = na
   })
    return nam for num;
}
```

But I don't know whether this works or not.

Comment: There are no numbers here; only strings. What have you done so far to sort your data? And what was the problem? And what do you mean with *"a for manner"*?

Comment: Seems like the arrays are in the order that you're describing? If new data comes along, you can use `.push()` to add the data to the end of both of your arrays, then the indexes for both arrays will associate both bits of data. Otherwise, if your goal is to "group"/"associate" two bits of data together, then you might be better of using an array of objects: `[{number: "91xxxx", name: "Abhi"}, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you will have a different function for pushing new data and retrieving the data.

```
function getAllOwners() {
return name.map((_name,index)=>_name+' '+number[index])
}// Output: [ 'Abhi 91xxxx', 'Arun 1xxxx', 'Aaron 92xxxx' ]
```

*Note that there's no need for the `async` keyword for there's no asynchronous operation here.

```
function addOwner(_name,num){
name.push(_name)
number.push(num)
}
```